# Getting sorted key value pairs from a dictionary based on two lists with unique elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists (`List1` and `List2` and a dictionary which comprises of key-value pairs, where the keys are elements of `List1+List2` and the values are numerical values.

What I want to return is a dictionary of dictionary where the key will be each element of List1 as key and the values will be all elements of List2 extracted from the dictionary.

As a theoretical example this is what I am trying to solve:

```
List_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

List_2 = ['E' ,'F' ,'G' ,'H']

Old_Dict = {'A':0.12, 'B':0.3, 'C':0.22, 'D':0.35, 'E':0.12, 'F':0.23, 'G':0.32, 'H':0.14}
```

What I want to return is (The dict values should be sorted by least absolute diff to highest absolute diff . that is  for the first key A the list difference is for `E (0.12-0.12)` the next is `H (0.14-0.12)` the next is `F(0.23-0.12)` and the next is `G(0.32-0.12)`, so the order is `E,H,F,G` while sorting the values.

New_dict (that gets returned)

```
{
    'A': {'E':0.12, 'H':0.14, 'F':0.23, 'G':0.32},
    'B': {'G':0.32, 'F':0.23, 'H':0.14, 'E':0.12},
    'C': {'F':0.23, 'H':0.14, 'E':0.12, 'G':0.32},
    'D': {'G':0.32, 'F':0.23, 'H':0.14, 'E':0.12}
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any ordering associated with dictionaries.

Comment: You could use a list of keys though.

Comment: Dictionary are unsorted by definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` doesn't need to be called in the inner loop.
And the `product_dict` is now in the desired form.

```
def Nearest_cluster (ListA,ListB,dict1):
    product_dict={}
    for elem in ListA:
        elem_val = dict1.get(elem)
        holding_dict = {}
        for item in ListB:
            item_val = dict1.get(item)
            diff = abs(elem_val - item_val)
            holding_dict[item] = diff
        holding_dict2 = sorted(holding_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
        product_dict[elem] = [(k[0],dict1[k[0]]) for k in holding_dict2]
    return product_dict

>>> Nearest_cluster(List_1, List_2, Old_Dict)
{'C': [('F', 0.23), ('H', 0.14), ('G', 0.32), ('E', 0.12)],
'B': [('G', 0.32), ('F', 0.23), ('H', 0.14), ('E', 0.12)],
'D': [('G', 0.32), ('F', 0.23), ('H', 0.14), ('E', 0.12)],
'A': [('E', 0.12), ('H', 0.14), ('F', 0.23), ('G', 0.32)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by the following method, but wanted to know if anyone had a better order of N operation:

```
def Nearest_cluster (ListA,ListB,dict1):
    product_dict = {}
    for elem in ListA:
        elem_val = dict1.get(elem)
        holding_dict = {}
        for item in ListB:
            item_val = dict1.get(item)
            diff = abs(elem_val-item_val)
            holding_dict[item] = diff
        holding_dict2=sorted(holding_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        product_dict[elem] = holding_dict2
    return product_dict
```